# Error in eval(bysub, x, parent.frame()) : object 'Year' not found

Tags: r, function, group-by, data.table, eval

I am trying to write a function using R data.table syntax. It has results if I just run this line `countbyYr = data[, .(counts = uniqueN(Col_A)), by = .(Year)]`, but once I put it into a function (shown below), it'll tell me `Error in eval(bysub, x, parent.frame()) : object 'Year' not found`.

```
counts_func <- function(df,groupby_col) {
  cnts<- df[, .(counts = uniqueN(Col_A)), by = .(groupby_col)]
  return(cnts)
}
countbyYr = counts_func(data,Year)
```

I've tried adding `get()` to get the column variable as some posts suggested, however, I'm still getting error messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`by` can also take a vector of column names (or a single quoted colum name), so you can do this:

```
counts_func <- function(df,groupby_col) {
  df[, .(counts = uniqueN(Col_A)), by = groupby_col]
}
countbyYr = counts_func(data,"Year")
```

Alternatively, you can also use `deparse(substitute())`, as below

```
counts_func <- function(df,bycol) {
  bycol  = deparse(substitute(bycol))
  df[, .(counts = uniqueN(Col_A)), bycol]
}
counts_func(data,Year)
```