# Error in creating function with data table syntax using multiple columns in as arguments for "by"

Tags: r, function, group-by, data.table

I am having trouble with using two columns as arguments for the data table argument "by" in a function.

The code below creates value-weighted portfolios according to different categories (e.g., state); where DT is a stacked dataframe containing stock prices for firms in the United States.

Here is my current code...

```
vw_testfunction <- function(bycol1, bycol2){
  
  vwret_df <- DT[,list(vw_ret = lapply(.SD,
                                       function(x) sum(x*mcap/sum(mcap,na.rm = TRUE),na.rm = TRUE))),
                 by = list(bycol1, bycol2), # adjust this line to manage grouping
                 .SDcols = "ret"]
  return(vwret_df)
}
 
test <- vw_testfunction("state", "datadate")
```

...where I get this error:

```r
Error in `[.data.table`(DT, , list(vw_ret = lapply(.SD, function(x) sum(x * : 
The items in the 'by' or 'keyby' list are length(s) (1,1). Each must be length 527561; the same length as there are rows in x (after subsetting if i is provided).
```

I have tried the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73116459/error-in-evalbysub-x-parent-frame-object-year-not-found), but using the arguments inside list() is causing the error.

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try `by=c(bycol1, bycol2)` instead of `list(bycol1, bycol2)`

Comment: BTW, writing your function to scope-breach to find its data can produce fragile (non-reproducible) results, and it can make troubleshooting difficult. Imagine a future-you that is working on a slightly modified dataset (perhaps named `DT2` because you are branching some data exploration), but your function keeps using the original `DT`. It's generally better -- even with in-place referential semantics such as `data.table` employs -- to pass the data to the function _explicitly_. Many prefer it to be the first argument or to name the arg `data=` (as many `base::`/`stats::` R functions do).

Comment: It would resolve some questions if you posted a sample of data; can you paste the output from `dput(head(DT,20))` into a code block in your question? Thanks!

Comment: For instance, you're using `lapply(.SD, ..)` which suggests that you expect there to be more than one column (other than the two grouping variables), yet you assign the results to a single column. If your frame has 10 rows and 2 other columns, this will result in 20 rows, since your `lapply(..)` is returning a list with two vectors, each length 10. Perhaps you don't need `vw_ret=`, instead just `DT[,lapply(.SD,...),by=c(bycol1,bycol2)]` or similar?